# Set time range with AJAX via another PHP file

Tags: php, ajax

I want to set time range in order to when the time is which I want then to display a video otherwise  displaying an image. Because I want to do this in client's time I want to take the website's time. So I did that ->

1st file (time.php):

```
<?php $b = time (); print date("H:i",$b); ?>
```

2nd file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/time.php",
        type: 'GET',        
        success: function(data){                    
            if($b >= 09:00 && $b < 10:00){ 
                document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="block"; 
                document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="none"; 
            } else{ 
                document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="block"; 
                document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="none";
            }
        }
    });
}, 1000);
<script>
```

I don't know what is wrong.
The browser console give me error on time ->

[ERROR] time 10:09:11.238 :: org.flowplayer.rtmp::SubscribingRTMPConnectionProvider : received onFCSubscribe

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's to use json like below
1st file (time.php):

```
<?php $b = time (); echo json_encode(array('date'=>date("H:i",$b)); ?>
```

2nd file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/time.php",
        type: 'GET',        
        success: function(data){
            var cur_date=Date.parse("01-01-2014 "+data.date+":00");//parase time
            var date1=Date.parse("01-01-2014 09:00:00");  
            var date2=Date.parse("01-01-2014 10:00:00");                    
            if(cur_date >= date1 && cur_date < data2){ 
                document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="block"; 
                document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="none"; 
            } else{ 
                document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="block"; 
                document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="none";
            }
        }
    });
}, 1000);
<script>
```

Comment: I tried it but no difference. Is it necessary the usage of date "01-01-2014"?

Comment: Also the time doesn't appear now in the page time.php

Comment: in ajax function you can add alert(data.date) to see where there is any output info

Comment: I have a question. The code that you gave for time.php shouldn't have displayed the time in browser when I open the page? Because the webpage does not display anything.

Comment: You mean in here? `$.ajax({
        url : "/time.php",
        type: 'GET',        
        success: function(data){
alert(data.date); 
            var cur_date=Date.parse("01-01-2014 "+data.date+":00");`